# Can infinitely many punch holes remove a unit square of paper?

Tags: measure-theory, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

Suppose there's a unit square of paper.

At each punch, remove the maximum hole possible.

For example, the initial maximum hole removed is

$\Large \pi r^2 = \pi (\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Repeating this process an infinite number of times, is it possible to remove all the paper?

[image: paper-holes]

Comment: You cannot remove all the points, for example at each step we can remove at most finitely many points on the boundary of the square, so we can remove at most countably many boundary points  in total.  However I suspect you can remove a set of total area equal to the area of the square.

Comment: What area of maths would be best suited for this type of problem? Fractals, set theory, infinite series, etc.,...?

Comment: Measure theory.  I have added that tag.

Comment: From the comment of @Michael  : "However I suspect you can remove a set of total area equal to the area of the square." What this means is that as you continue the process, the limit of the *unpunched area* goes to $(0)$.

Comment: A *very informal* alternative idea is to (invalidly) presume that if the entire square can be covered in an infinite number of *moves*, then it can be covered in a finite number of moves.  Then, just before the last (finite) move, the *unpunched* region must represent a perfect circle.  However, this **informally suggests** a contradiction, because it seems that no move ever  results in all of the remaining *unpunched* region forming a perfect circle.

Comment: Theoretically, Tangent segments have only one point removed from the square edge. You start with 4 with the first circle, than 8 with the next 4 circles and the remaining nested circles remove only only one point. Now the question what you mean by infinite - convergence is not working.